# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have been following a video tutorial on youtube for an AJAX upload, i know a fair amount of javascript, jquery, etc but this has me stumped.

my code is below, can anyone enlighten me as to why this is happening when i try to uploade more than one file or in some cases 1 file.

I have included my code below, its not perfect as i said i was follwoing along with a video tutorial.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_FILES['file']))
{
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key=>$name)
{
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']       [$key], "uploads/{$name}"))
    {
        $uploaded[] = $name;
    }
}

if (!empty($_POST['ajax']))
{
    die(json_encode($uploaded));
}
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="upload.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
#upload_progress {display: none;}
</style>
<body>

<div id="uploaded">
        <?php
            if(!empty($uploaded))
            {
                foreach ($uploaded as $name) {
                    echo '<div><a href="uploads/'.$name.'">'.$name.'</a></div>';
                }
            }
        ?>
</div>

<div id="upload_progress"></div>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="upload">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And my JS file is

```
var handleUpload = function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');

var data = new FormData();

data.append('ajax', true);

for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; ++i)
{
    data.append('file[]', fileInput.files[i]);
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable)
    {
        var percent = event.loaded / event.total;
        var progress = document.getElementById('upload_progress');
        while (progress.hasChildNodes())
        {
            progress.removeChild(progress.firstChild);
        }
        progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Math.round(percent * 100) + '%'));
    }



});

request.upload.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('upload_progress').style.display = 'none';
});

request.upload.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
    alert("Upload Failed");
});

request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event) {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200)
        {
            var links = document.getElementById('uploaded');
            console.log(this.response);
            var uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);
            var div, a;

            for (var i = 0; i < uploaded.length; i++)
            {
                div = document.createElement('div');
                a = document.createElement('a');
                a.setAttribute('href', 'uploads/' + uploaded[i]);
                a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uploaded[i]));
                div.appendChild(a);
                links.appendChild(div); 
            }
        } else {
            console.log("error" + this.response);
        }
    }
});

request.open('POST', 'index.php');
request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');

document.getElementById('upload_progress').style.display = 'block';

request.send(data);


}

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener('click', handleUpload);

});
```

Initially the video had me using eval for the variable uploaded, i changed this to JSON.parse, i don't want a quick fix but rather an answer as to why this isn't working?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct?

Comment: What's the entire error message with the line containing the error

Comment: Yeah if I use a single file it formats it fine, if I use multiple files it returns the source of index. php rather than the job formatted array I just can't see why it would do that..

Comment: @Ahmad - the subject is the error message caught by chrome console

Comment: In the console at the right side it should tell you the line containing the error

Comment: @Ahmad - line 49 / var uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);

Comment: And what does `console.log(this.response);` returned

Comment: @Ahmad - the code breaks before that line is executed because it gets a response so it returns 200 but the json array is not an array

Comment: Your php is returning div elements ??

Comment: @Ahmad - the php is the fall back for none js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, inside the php.ini file there is a size restriction on my server for file uploads, i increased that and it works fine now.

Anyone else who has the same problem check your upload size!